# Python Convolve2D functionality in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, python

I am new to mathematica. I am looking for an alternative for `scipy.signal.convolve2d`.
I did find functions like `ListConvolve`, but it returns a 1D array whereas I expect a 2-dimensional array containing a subset of the discrete linear convolution. Also help me as to how can i specify mode as "same" like in numpy.

Convolve2D:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html

Python code (using NumPy)

```
d = convolve2d(var, kernel, mode="same")
```

Mathematica Code

```
d = ListConvolve[kernel,var]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although I'm sure that some users here are conversant in NumPy, many here (including myself, for instance) may not know what the `convolve2D` function does, and what its output should be. You may want to expand your description, and perhaps include an example with expected output, a link to a documentation page, or similar.

Comment: You'll want to look at the third overhang argument and the fourth padding argument of `ListConvolve[]`; in particular, `ListConvolve[]` does not pad by default, so you explicitly need to give a fourth argument of `0` if you want it to act like the corresponding function on NumPy.

Comment: Also note that `ListConvolve` does in fact work with 2D arrays as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like J.M. said, the use of `ListConvolve` can be a bit tricky, because by default it cuts overhangs and has no padding. From your description i guess you are more interested in something like this:

```
MatrixPlot[
  ListConvolve[GaussianMatrix[10], BoxMatrix[20] - DiamondMatrix[20], {1, -1}, {0, 0}]
]
```

[image: ListConvolve 2D convolution example]

$\mspace{172mu}\Big\Updownarrow$

$\mspace{30mu}$[image: ListConvolve input]

This uses the overhang parameters `{1,-1}` to have maximum overhang on both ends. The next parameter `{0,0}` adds zero padding in both dimensions to make sure we don't get cyclical convolution (which is the default).

For more details see the documentation of `ListConvolve` but this example should get you started ;)